# On page load event for single paged JavaScript applications?

Tags: javascript

I'm asking for single paged JavaScript applications where the page does not make a full request. Specifically for a site like YouTube where the initial request is a full request and everything else is a `XMLHttpRequest` where only the body is changing client side.

An example would be YouTube. I want to do something like this:

1. You go to YouTube.com and click on one of the videos.
2. When the video page finishes loading, `console.log("page loaded");`

Is there an event listener I can add for when the page loads?

Comment: I guess you can do something like add an event listener for all the links and if they are local ones, do XHR, if not, follow them. Your question is either too broad or kinda unclear.

Comment: Well, it depends on your way of requesting async data. You can always trigger your action on XMLHttpRequest successful response.

Answer (score 0):

No events are being fired when the DOM is modified, so it's not possible to add a listener on anything like that.

You will have to keep track of the modifications on the DOM, manually. You could add "callbacks" to the modification functions you use:

```
function addSomethingToPage(data){
    data.doSomething():
    domReady();
}

function domReady(){
    //re-usable "callback"
}
```